# css printable size and pdf

Tags: html, css, pdf

I have my course book as html parts chapter-by-chapter. I have done some modifies on it. It seems very well when it is read on webpage but when I want to convert it to pdf or print it it seems narrow. The issue is that how the page can be fitted in A4. If you look at `output.pdf` which can be found on main page. Besides, the shared links for you understand me. (especially page 47). I can merge them just in a pdf file. I think that if the css can be edited, it will be fitted in A4 and seems in pdf like a book. I need your helps. As an example you can look at `ch18.html` and `ch19.pdf` I can't write other links because of reputation. But all files can be looked from main page.

Pages: http://bookfiles.host-ed.me/ch18.html and ch19.html

Css file: http://bookfiles.host-ed.me/static/CACHE/css/ab0ffefbadc3.css

I absolutetly newbie about css. Thank for your helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue appears to be with your **max-width** on your "document" div. You have it set at several different places in your css file based on the screen size. I would go through them one by one and find the one that is affecting your print file. You need to set your max-width to 100%. Having a max-width less than 100% is what is causing it to print narrow.

Once you identify which one is causing the problem, you can add a new style that only goes into affect when you print.

Add this to your CSS file, for example:

```
@media print and (color){
    #lesson-fragment, [role="document"] {
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
```

You can also put other specific print styles inside of the @media print code. Like if you wanted to change the font size or color only when it printed.